# Problems with encoding files when running standalone jar

Tags: java, maven, encoding, maven-2, character-encoding

I've got strangest problem. I have a java class that writes some data to a file. When I execute it in the eclipse all works fine (writting data in the right encoding). But when I run it as standalone JAR the encoding is broken.

I have this in my project (in pom.xml) :

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

My java class has property in eclipse (right click -> properties) file encoding set to : UTF-8.

Here is java code snipped that does appending :

```
 //class field
    static BufferedWriter wr;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(args[0], true), "UTF-8");
        wr = new BufferedWriter(writer);
        //.processing logic, building up what needs to be in the file, line by line
        wr.close();
    }
```

Relevant method that does appending to .csv file :

```
private void writeToCSVFile(String content){

        try {
            System.out.println(content);
            wr.write(content);
            wr.write("\n");
            wr.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Again when I print in the eclipse the output looks fine just as it does in the file I'm appending to. But when running as standalone jar encoding breaks for some reason. This is how I configure my relevant plugin(s) :

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>Worker</finalName>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.test.automation.Testing</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I really have no clue what to do next. Any ideas?

**This code doesn't have any exceptions, doesn't fail anywhere. Runs exactly as intended in eclipse, when I check the file in which the results are written.**

It works as standalone jar as well, but only when I check the file in which results are written encoding is screwed up.

Comment: How do you know the encoding is broken? Because of the output file?

Answer (score 2):

All the settings you showed us do indeed specify the encoding to be used for EDITING and COMPILING your code.

It does not say anything about the encoding used when you RUN your code.

Apparently, the jvm used by eclipse uses UTF-8 as its `file.encoding` property.

You standalone jvm uses another value for its file.encoding property.

Moreover, the problem arise when you READ the data, not when you WRITE it as you specified the "UTF-8" encoding for output explicitly.

You have 2 solutions:

**Solution 1:**

You NEVER EVER read anything with the default encoding (always create readers by specifying the correct encoding).

**Solution 2:**

You tell your jvm what should be its default encoding:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that your eclipse environnment is not the same as a standalone environment, I will put my money on missing classes in your jar file. When you're exporting your jar file in eclipse ensure that you package referenced jars otherwise your program will fail. is there any stack trace when the program fails?

Comment: I never said that program fails. It run very smootly, exactly as I intended